# Flex/Bison Matching 2 different patterns with no spaces between them

Tags: regex, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I'm a beginner with Flex and Bison and I have a question since the field of regexp is new to me.

I have strings to scan like "LOL TATA 93.00"
but the thing is, white spaces are MANDATORY between 2 words with letters, but OPTIONAL between word with letters/word with numbers.
I can have strings like
"LOL TATA93.00"
"LOL TATA 93.00"
but never "LOLTATA 93.00".

My problem is , I can scan and analyse easily when there are spaces. (found LOL then TATA then 93.00)
But when I have TATA93.00, it fails, it takes TATA93.00 as 1 word, but I would like that it recognizes first TATA as a word then, 93.00 as another one.

I cannot add a rule in the Flex file like  [A-Z]+[0-9.]+ because if I have to give all possibilities, It will never end.

My question is: is Bison able to see TATA93.00 as 2 words I defined by [A-Z]{4} and [0-9.]+ respectively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flex always recognizes the longest possible match to a pattern. So if your patterns are:

```
[A-Z]+
[0-9.]+
```

and the (current) input is `LOLTATA93.00`, then flex will match `LOLTATA` and then match `93.00` which seems to be what you want. Assuming that you are ignoring whitespace, then the same thing would happen with input `LOLTATA 93.00`.

You need to be more precise about exactly what you consider to be a "word". Is it at most four letters long? Can it contain digits? (I presume the answer to the second question is "no", but it's not clear from the question.) Only by being precise about what you want to match can you write a precisely correct pattern to match it.

Comment: Silly me. I looked at your answer and thought "for me it is not working". I began to write a code to expose here, tested it and it worked. Then I looked at my original code, and I realized I had a rule in my flex file which was ruining the others. Thanks still for making me think twice.